# FBSDKAccessToken losing permissions from FBSDKLoginButton on Swift 3

Tags: ios, facebook, swift3, facebook-login, facebook-access-token

I'm trying to make a Facebook Login in my App. I'm creating the login button this way:

```
var loginButton = FBSDKLoginButton() 
loginButton.readPermissions = ["public_profile", "user_friends",  "email", "user_posts"]
loginButton.publishPermissions = ["publish_actions"]
```

But I notice that the Facebook Login Page do not ask me all these permissions (it only asks me public_profile), as you can see in the following image:

**Facebook Login Page Asked Permissions:**
[image]

Then, I put a breakpoint in function called after Login, as you can see in the image:

**Breaking point in LoginButtonFunction didCompleteWith result:**
[image]

At this breakpoint I notice that my FBSDKAccessToken does not have all my readPermissions  (it only has public_profile), as you can see in the following images:

**BSDKAccessToken permissions:**
[image]

But my button still have those permissions asked at this same breakpoint:

[image]

Why is it happening? I'm I doing something wrong? I tried deleting this App from my Facebook Accepted apps, but the problem persists.

If it helps, thats my AppDelegate and Info.plist:

**AppDelegate:**
[image]

**info.plist:**
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Probably you'll not need this anymore, but I'll answer for people that had similar problem like myself.

You have two problems:

1. Is that you need set yourself as Developer in the Facebook App, without that you will not see this message:

> Invalid Scopes: publish_actions. This message is only
>   shown to developers. Users of your app will ignore these permissions
>   if present. Please read the documentation for valid permissions at:
>   https://developers.facebook.com/docs/facebook-login/permissions

2. This permission will not be valid from August 1st 2018 (apps that already have this one also will not be allowed), beyond that you only have available the simple share dialog (and if I'm not mistaken you can't pre-populate with text). You can check this info on https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/changelog/breaking-changes

> The publish_actions permission has been removed. Apps that have
>   already been approved for publish_actions can continue using the
>   permission until August 1st, 2018. If you want to provide a way for
>   your app users to share content to Facebook and Instagram beyond this
>   date, we encourage you to use our Sharing products instead.